# Why doesn't current flow through the resistor in cases where transistors A and B are on?

Tags: transistors, current, digital-logic, ground

I was watching this video and wondering why the current doesn't flow through the resistor and through the transistors A and B at the same time. Why does it have to flow only through A and B? (Bottom Left)

[image: XOR Gate]

Comment: The bottom left BJT's will turn off the middle BJT. Thus there is no path for A and B (on the right) emitter current to flow because the middle BJT's is OFF by bottom left BJT's.

Comment: you can see that there will be much less resistive path when Both A and B are on (i.e. It's like a short ) except for the collector emitter junctions drop in both transistors which in ideal case will be completely zero voltage so no current to activate the middle BJT. and hence no current through the resistor

Comment: I am talking about just the bottom left transistors here and Note that ( in case you didn't know )  transistor's ( especially in digital electronics ) is considered with it's ideal switch model so you can just replace them with a switch and it will be all clear to you

Comment: Please put reference designators (Q1, Q2, R1, R2, etc) on the components in your schematic, and use them in your question, so we can see what transistors and resistors you are asking about.

Comment: Which resistor is "the resistor"? There are 4 resistors in your circuit.

Comment: there are two transistors labeled `A` and two transistors labeled `B` ... which ones are you asking about?

Comment: I think this is supposed to be someone's idea of an XOR gate. Just FYI. In the sense that the LED will be lit if only only if the **A** and **B** inputs are different. (They would need to be fed via a resistor, so let's not get into misunderstandings over that issue.)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the small resistance of open transistors compared to the resistor.
Selecting the value of the top resistor and the value of the right resistor you will make such voltage on base of the right transistor that will be less than base-emitter turn-on voltage. Just imaging that left transistors turn into to a very little resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Current always choses the path that have minimum resistance. The transistors, when turned ON, have minimum resistance (think it as short circuit) but the resistor (connected with the collector of upper transistor) have very high resistance as compared to short circuit. So current flows through those 2 transistors when turned ON otherwise the current will flow through the resistor when the bottom left transistors are OFF. Hope it helps.

Comment: Technically, the current flows though **all** possible paths, however, its magnitude is inversely proportional to each path's resistance. For paths with drastically different resistances it looks like "minimum resistance" path is chosen, but saying that it's *always* the case is false.